# How do I define a vector, and store objects in it with C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm trying to define two vectors for a simple, console based email server; one for storing inbox messages, and the other for storing sent messages. Each message object (vector element) has 3 string attributes. And thanks to advice from Galik, my updated code is much cleaner, constructors are made, and my getters and setters are also done. However, despite all this progress, I still am unsure how (and where) to assign the 3 attributes into one message object to be used as a vector element. Where do I do this in my new code?:

Header File:

```
    //Message.h constructs the setup for email messages
#ifndef MESSAGE_H
#define MESSAGE_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
//using namespace std;//should not use in header file.

//prototype functions
void viewInboxMessage();

class Message
{
private:
    std::string address;
    std::string subject;
    std::string text;
    std::vector<Message> inbox;
    std::vector<Message> sent;

public:
    Message()//default constuctor
    {
        //set all member variables to NULL at start of program:
        vector<Message> inbox(0);
        vector<Message> sent(0);
        address = "";
        subject = "";
        text = "";      
    }
    //contructor for message object
    Message(string address, string subject, string text);

    void setAddress(string addr);
    string getAddress();

    void setSubject(string subj);
    string getSubject();

    void setMessageText(string msgTxt);
    string getMessageText();    
};
#endif
```

.cpp Function File (separate from file with main function):

```
    //This class instantiates a message object for populating the
//vector arrays.
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include "Message.h"
using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes:
//Message inbox(string, string, string);
//Message sent(string, string, string);
void viewInboxMessage();

Message::Message(string address, string subject, string text)
{
    setAddress(address);
    setSubject(subject);
    setMessageText(text);
}

//START OF GETTERS AND SETTERS
void Message::setAddress(string addr)
{
    address = addr;
}
string Message::getAddress()
{
    return address;
}

void Message::setSubject(string subj)
{
    subject = subj;
}
string Message::getSubject()
{
    return subject;
}

void Message::setMessageText(string msgTxt)
{
    text = msgTxt;
}
string Message::getMessageText()
{
    return text;
}
//END OF GETTERS AND SETTERS

//Main Menu option 1 selected:
// print list of all messages to the console
void viewInbox()
{
    cout << "You have " << inbox.size << " new messages.\n";
    std::cout << "Index      Subject" << '\n';

    for (size_t i = 0; i < inbox.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << "    : " << inbox[i].subject << '\n';
    }
}

//write a function that will display as many case break switch choices
//as there are messages in the inbox

//print selected message to console:
void viewInboxMessage(size_t index)
{
    if (index < inbox.size())//error: identifier "inbox" is not defined.
    {
        std::cout << "Message Number : " << index << '\n';
        std::cout << "sender: " << inbox[index].address << '\n';
        std::cout << "subject: " << inbox[index].subject << '\n';
        std::cout << "message: " << '\n';
        std::cout << inbox[index].text << '\n';
    }
}

//Main Menu option 3 selected:
Message newMessage(string address, string subject, string compose)
{
    cout << "Please enter recipient email address.\n";
    cin >> address;
    cout << "Please enter a subject for your message.\n";
    cin >> subject;
    cout << "Go ahead and type your message, and hit send when you're finished.\n";
    cin >> compose;
    vector<Message> viewSent(0)++;//add composed message to sent messages list after user sends it.
}
```

File With Main Function:

```
    //This class contains the main function and the main menu.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

#include "Message.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Message inbox[10];
    vector<Message> inbox;
    Message sent[10];
    string sender; 
    string subject;
    int numMessages;//number of messages in inbox
    int choice = 0;

    string verify = "Cartman2010";
    string userName;
    string address;
    string password;
    cout << "please enter your login username.\n";
    cin >> userName;
    cout << "please enter your email address.\n";
    cin >> address;
    cout << "please enter your password.\n";
    cin >> password;
    if (password != verify)
    {
        cout << "Invalid password. Please re-enter your password.\n";
        cin >> password;
    }
    else

    cout << "Hello " << userName << " Welcome to your mailbox. Please select an option:\n";

    //After easy login and greeting, the user needs to select an option form the main menu:
    cout << "1. View Your Inbox\n";
    cout << "2. View Sent Messages\n";
    cout << "3. Send A Message\n";
    cout << "4. Quit\n";

    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: Message viewInbox;//access messages (and number of messages) from vector inbox
        break;
    case 2: Message viewSent;//view the messages you've sent (and how many) from vector
        break;
    case 3: Message newMessage;
        break;
    case 4: exit();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Where am I supposed to assign the 3 strings, "address", "subject", and "text" into a Message object vector element?

Comment: When your function is of data type Message, you'll have to return the data type message, and not strings in the message.

Comment: Okay, but then where do I tell the program that the message object consists of the 3 attributes? Obviously, a returning a message object without those 3 specifications wouldn't be correct.

Comment: Please see @Galik answer. I think that's the correct approach to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You say your `Message` objects should have 3 string attributes but your `Message` has 6. Also you appear to be trying to fit the whole mail-server into your Message class. I'm not sure of your whole criteria but perhaps this kind of structure might be helpful:

```
struct Message
{
    std::string address; // sender/recipient
    std::string subject;
    std::string text; // actual message

    // compose message functions here
};

class EmailServer
{
private:
    std::vector<Message> inbox;
    std::vector<Message> sent;

public:

    // mail server functions here ...

    // print list of all messages to the console
    void viewInbox()
    {
        std::cout << "Index      Subject" << '\n';

        for(size_t i = 0; i < inbox.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << i << "    : " << inbox[i].subject << '\n';
        }
    }

    // print a specific message to the console
    void viewInboxMessage(size_t index)
    {
        if(index < inbox.size())
        {
            std::cout << Message Number: " << index << '\n';
            std::cout << "sender: " << inbox[index].address << '\n';
            std::cout << "subject: " << inbox[index].subject << '\n';
            std::cout << "message: " << '\n';
            std::cout << inbox[index].text << '\n';
        }
    }


};
```

Comment: Yeah, another thing about that. If I'm declaring the getters and setters for all 3 attributes in the viewInbox function, do I still need the other individual getters and setters commented out below them?

Comment: @SamJava_The_Hut To be honest I don't really understand your viewInbox function. What I assume it should do from your comment is list all the elements from the `inbox` vector. Probably just the titles and the index. I would put that function in the EmailServer class.

Comment: @SamJava_The_Hut Also, you should follow the advice of your tutor, but I am not a big fan of getters and setters which is why my `Message` class is declared as a `struct` with all the data members public so they can be set directly.

Comment: Galik, why are you repetitively using std:: instead of just declaring using namespace std; at the top of your file?

Comment: You should never use `using naespace ...` in a header file where you define your classes because that will pollute other people's code. It is acceptable, however, if you put your code in its own namespace to use it there. The namespace `std::`, however, is particularly large so I almost never have `using namespace std;` anywhere. It drags in so many symbols, many of which are common names programmers like to use all the time (like count) that it can cause many subtle hard to find bugs. FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/using-namespace-std.html

Comment: I do have `using namespace ...` in my `.cpp` files a lot. There it won't pollute other people's code. Even then I avoid `using namespace std;` because that is such a large namespace and like I said... subtle bugs... hard to find.

Comment: Also, in practice, I actually `typedef` a lot of things so its much rarer to find `std::` in my working code than my examples may suggest.